# python function as class attribute - AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have python module 'test.p'y with function 'threads' accepting function 'ping' as argument which works as expected

```
def ping(ip):
    print "ping", ip

def port(ip):
    print "port", ip

def threads(conn, ip):
    conn(ip)

ping('address')
threads(ping, 'address')
```

giving me output of ping('address') same as threads(ping, 'address')

> ## python test.py
>
> ping address
>
> ping address

Now I need to replace function 'threads' with class 'Threads' and use function 'ping' as class attribute which doesn't work

```
def ping(ip):
    print "ping", ip

def port(ip):
    print "port", ip

class Threads():
    def __init__(self, func, addr):
        self.conn = func
        self.ip = addr

    def popqueue(self):
        print "popqueue"

    def dequeue(self):
        self.popqueue()
        self.conn(self.ip)

    def start(self):
        self.dequeue()


ping('address')

threads = Threads(ping, 'address')
threads.start()
```

and this gives an error below:

> ## python rep2.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "rep2.py", line 78, in  threads.start()
> File "rep2.py", line 42, in start self.dequeue()
> File "rep2.py", line 39, in dequeue self.conn()
>
> AttributeError: 'Threads' object has no attribute 'conn'

How do i do it correctly ?

Comment: What version of Python is this? It should work in more recent versions, but if you're running a really old version, you may be running into some of the things that have changed about classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the posted code. Works fine.

Note, that contrary to what you've wrote, you set an *instance* attribute, and not a class attribute.

Comment: Python 2.6.6 ...hm I will try a newer one thnx

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can see someone doing so if they feel that your post should have been a comment or "can no longer be reproduced" close vote.

Comment: @irom: that won't fix it. there's nothing wrong with the code. copy paste it from HERE.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work OK using python 2.7.8. It gives me this output

```
ping address
popqueue
ping address
```